# How to avoid hardcoding of colors in D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I've taught myself d3 (still learning), and have a finished visualisation that I'm more than happy with.

But i think (know) that the code can be improved and made more efficient. For instance, use a csv file for the data (don't know where to begin with that). But more specifically, i'd like to know how the hard coded colours  can be used directly with d3, but categorised by cancer, diabetes, CHD (exactly how i've hardcoded them). Additionally, rather than use the messy html and css i have for the titles, is there anything that can be done via d3?

I believe i'm pretty good with html and css, but i was a little daunted by d3 and the html/css are inherently mess.

I've attached an image of what it looks like (please ignore the data under South England: I know it's duplicated; I have to replace them with the actual data).

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300");

rect {
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Lato";
  fill: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:17px;
  position: fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.p1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.p2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 550px;
}

.p3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p4 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 230px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p5 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 380px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p6 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p7 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 283px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p8 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 553px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p9 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 723px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p10 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 896px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p11 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 552px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}

.p12 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 810px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>TreeMap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
    <section class="container1">
      <p class="p1"> North England </p><p class="p2"> South England </p>
      <p class="p3"> Bradford City </p><p class="p4"> Leeds </p>
      <p class="p5"> Liverpool </p><p class="p6"> Manchester </p>
      <p class="p7"> Sheffield </p><p class="p8"> Brighton </p>
      <p class="p9"> Bristol </p><p class="p10"> Luton </p>
      <p class="p11"> Milton Keynes </p><p class="p12"> Southampton </p>
      <object class="Box" class="cancer"></object>
    </section>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#A8A7A7",
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
              "color": "#2F9599",
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
              "color": "#E8175D",
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
              "color": "#474747",
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
              "color": "#CC527A",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Leeds",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.52,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.29,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.71,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.82,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Liverpool",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 5.90,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.71,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.70,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.88,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Manchester",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.78,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 2.95,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.61,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.05,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheffield",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.54,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 4.57,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.85,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.08,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "South England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Brighton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bristol",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Luton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Milton Keynes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color":"#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Southampton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#A8A7A7",
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
            "color": "#2F9599",
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
            "color": "#E8175D",
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
            "color": "#474747",
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
            "color": "#CC527A",
          }
        ]
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1000, 600])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return 0.8 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */ })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { if (d.data.color) {
                                  return d.data.color
                                } else {
                                  return "white"
                                }})
  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 10)
    .attr('dy', 8)
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.value;
  });


  </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used d3, so I may be asking the wrong question, but could you not simply use `d.data.name` as a class name when adding a rectangle, and in your CSS specify colours for each of the types (Cancer, CKD etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal way for d3 - it is a using ordinal color scale. You should associate names of disease with appropriate colors:

```
var namesOfDisease = ["Cancer", "CKD", "CHD", "Diabetes", "Stroke"];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(namesOfDisease)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599" , "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);
```

It returns appropriate color when you pass desease name as argument:

```
console.log(color("Cancer")) // ==> #A8A7A7
console.log(color("CHD")) // ==> #E8175D
console.log(color("Stroke")) // ==> #CC527A
```

And use this scale for color applying:

```
...
.attr('fill', function(d) {
    var result = null;

  if (namesOfDisease.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
    result = color(d.data.name);
  } else {
    result = 'white'
  }

  return result;
})
...
```

Check demo without hardcoded colors in the hidden snippet:

```js
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "North England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Bradford City",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Cancer",
              "value": 1.18,
            },
            {
              "name": "CKD",
              "value": 3.21,
            },
            {
              "name": "CHD",
              "value": 2.57,
            },
            {
              "name": "Diabetes",
              "value": 11.92,
            },
            {
              "name": "Stroke",
              "value": 1.18,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Leeds",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.52,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.29,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.71,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.82,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Liverpool",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.50,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 5.90,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.71,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 6.70,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.88,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Manchester",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.78,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 2.95,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.61,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.05,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Sheffield",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 2.54,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 4.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 3.85,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 7.08,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 2.13,
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "South England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Brighton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Bristol",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Luton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Milton Keynes",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Southampton",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Cancer",
            "value": 1.18,
          },
          {
            "name": "CKD",
            "value": 3.21,
          },
          {
            "name": "CHD",
            "value": 2.57,
          },
          {
            "name": "Diabetes",
            "value": 11.92,
          },
          {
            "name": "Stroke",
            "value": 1.18,
          }
        ]
      },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1000, 600])
  .paddingTop(20)
  .paddingInner(8);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

treemapLayout(rootNode);

var namesOfDisease = ["Cancer", "CKD", "CHD", "Diabetes", "Stroke"];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(namesOfDisease)
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599" , "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})

  nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('opacity', function(d) { return 0.8 /* has to be like d.value / max or so */ })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
     var result = null;
      
      if (namesOfDisease.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
       result = color(d.data.name);
      } else {
       result = 'white'
      }
      
      return result;
    })
  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 10)
    .attr('dy', 8)
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.value;
  });
```

```css
rect {
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Lato";
  fill: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top:17px;
  position: fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.p1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.p2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 550px;
}

.p3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p4 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 230px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p5 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 380px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p6 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p7 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 283px;
  padding-top: 390px;
}

.p8 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 553px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p9 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 723px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p10 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 896px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.p11 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 552px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}

.p12 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Lato";
  padding-left: 810px;
  padding-top: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
    <section class="container1">
      <p class="p1"> North England </p><p class="p2"> South England </p>
      <p class="p3"> Bradford City </p><p class="p4"> Leeds </p>
      <p class="p5"> Liverpool </p><p class="p6"> Manchester </p>
      <p class="p7"> Sheffield </p><p class="p8"> Brighton </p>
      <p class="p9"> Bristol </p><p class="p10"> Luton </p>
      <p class="p11"> Milton Keynes </p><p class="p12"> Southampton </p>
      <object class="Box" class="cancer"></object>
    </section>
  </svg>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! But i have a question, how does the constant variable namesOfDisease selects the correct child? I'm a bit confused with this

Comment: Did you confuse with this syntax? `[].map(d => d.name)`. It is an ES6 feature - "Arrow function" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions It is the same that `[].map(function(d) { return d.name; })`. I changed it in the demo with traditional syntax.

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more specific, i meant this data.children[0].children[0].children.map 
How can this map to the diseases, rather than city or north/south england?

Comment: Oh. `data` object is a nested array so I just analyze the structure and get the first child with the list of diseases with this long path `.children[0].children[0].children`.

Comment: I think. If you are sure the list of disease will not change it would be better to  just define `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Cancer", "CKD", "CHD", "Diabetes", "Stroke"])
  .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599" , "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);`

Comment: Yeah, i think that makes sense. How would i reflect the change in the code below that appends the colour? 

    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      var result = null;

        if (namesOfDiseases.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
          result = color(d.data.name);
        } else {
          result = "white"
        }

      return result;

Comment: You can continue to use `namesOfDisease` variable to avoid code duplication. You just define this variable with the array of possible names of disease (check the answer I updated it). In this case, you do not need to change fragment of code that you mentioned.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help!